# Why is my UITableView not registering the first touch after scrolling?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xamarin.ios, touch

In my app I have a `UITableView` on a `UIView`. The `UITableView` does not register the first tap if I scroll first. The touch event fires properly on the second tap and works fine if I don't scroll. This happens to the bottom table item every time (unless I scroll to it then back up and then back down and then touch) but only happens to other table items the first time I show the view after opening the app.

Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong?

UPDATE:
I've just added tap gesture recognizers to all subviews of the `UIView` that hosts the `UITable` (after all controls have been added). The gesture recognizer adds a colored border to the `UIView` that received the tap. When I scroll the table down and tap the bottom item, a border appears around the items (all of them, not individual cells) that were visible before scrolling.

SOLVED:
The problem was that when swiping up and the swipe gesture ended off of the `UITableView`, the scroll didn't finish (the scrollbar was still visible on the right, I just didn't notice it). The first tap cancels the scroll...

Comment: Your RowSeleted method is not firing?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes, that's what happening. On the first touch, the method doesn't fire. On the second, it does. I just can't figure out why...

Comment: Did you get the answer to this one?
For me, after a dismiss ViewController, the parent ViewController doesn't register the first click, the second click works just fine.